# Issue while connecting to orchestrator through chatbot-bridge version 2 api. (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, chatbot, uipath, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-api

We are trying to connect dialog-flow api (v2) with ui-path orchestrator using chatbot-bridge(v2 code) but we are seeing this below error.

This is the configuration file:
default.json:

```
{
    "server": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 6543
    },
    "orchestrator": {
        "hostname": "platform.uipath.com",
        "tenancyName": "xxxxxxxx",
        "usernameOrEmailAddress": "xxxxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    "dialogflow": {
        "private_key": "xxxxxx",
        "projectId": "115556440368131734996"
    },
}
```

Error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed
with error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (D:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:30:26)
    at Http2CallStream.<anonymous> (D:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:96:33)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:214:15)
    at D:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:97:22
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
(node:13808) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:13808) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please let me know if there is any solution for this, we stuck here. We looked in UI-Path forum we didn't see any posts related to it.

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, I did find the solution, someone has posted the latest version of that SDK. There was an issue with the configuration also.

Comment: OK, thanks for update

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have already found a solution to this, but I would like to highlight the fact that we have released in public preview a PaaS for chatbots:

https://forum.uipath.com/t/chatbot-connector-now-in-public-preview/210724

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I will look into it.